# Screen is flickring and Game is stucked in AndEngine Android

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am working on a game which is almost developed. When I play the game some times it is working fine but some times the screen starts flickering and game is stuck.

Can any one tell me what this issues could be because in the logs there are no errors.

If someone has experienced this issue please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this mistake when I had problems with tiled maps. Actually it depended on my mistakes with creating TiledMap and on choosing wrong texture sizes for it. If you have tiledmaps in your game check your parameters once more

Comment: no im not using any tiled maps but im using near about 600 assets

Comment: If you are using GLES2.0 then your sprite's dimensions must be of power of 2's. Have a look on it.

Comment: m using 1.0 and it also needs power of twos

Comment: I'm not using all the time dimensions of 2's power(Gles 2). But i've never faced the mistake in using them in a such way